# How to make the binary file so that the interpreter of this file is /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so？

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, cross-compiling, arm64, nwjs

I directly use the binary file you released to test on my arm64-based computer. But the test result is not normal operation. The reason is that nw interpreter needs to be /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instead of /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 on Linux version 4.19.172 for arm64.

How to compile the binary file so that the interpreter of this file is /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so?

```
$ file ./nwjs-chromium-ffmpeg-branding/nwjs-v0.52.3-linux-arm/nw
$ ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[xxHash]=4c8a98c5d541ac00, stripped
```

But, I want to get a binary executable file like this：

```
$ file ./nwjs-chromium-ffmpeg-branding/nwjs-v0.52.3-linux-arm/nw
$ ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[xxHash]=4c8a98c5d541ac00, stripped
```

Comment: The dynamic linker is specified as DT_INTERP field in the ELF (.so) file. You can either tell the linker to write a specific path in there (`--dynamic-linker` for GNU ld), or modify the file after linking e.g. with `patchelf`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65179573/420683

Comment: Actually, this is probably an architecture mismatch. armhf is probably 32-bit (and aarch64 64-bit of course). See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87403

Comment: `I want to get a binary executable file` Recompile the file for the architecture.

Comment: "I directly use the binary file you released" - Sounds like you're talking to the wrong people here.